# add all the values from all objects in dataset

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset

So i've got a dataset with movie ratings, each movie got multiple ratings.
I managed to get all the data but i want to add all the values.

for example:

`title: avatar, rating: 2.5`
`title: avatar, rating: 3`
`title: avatar, rating 5`

`rating = 10.5`

`avrRating = 10.5 / ratings.lenght = 3.5`

my code so far:

(it picks a random movie, then it matches its movieId with the movieId from another dataset. Then i convert the range from 0-5 to 0-100 to match it with the width in data2. rating[i].rating shows me multiple values, but i want the avarage value, ***see example above*** )

```
function willekeurigObject() {

  var blokje = document.querySelector("#data1");
  var blokje = document.querySelector("#data2");
  var blokje = document.querySelector("#data3");

  var willekeurigAdres = Math.floor(Math.random() * films.length);
  var willekeurigefilm = films[willekeurigAdres];

  for (var i = 0; i < rating.length; i++){
    if (rating[i].movieId == willekeurigefilm.movieId){
      var ratings = rating[i].rating;
    }
  }

  var width = (ratings / 0.05) + "%";


  data1.innerHTML = willekeurigefilm.title;
  data2.innerHTML = "<div class='stars'><img src='img/starsinv.png' class='img'></img><div class='yellow' style='width: " + width + "'></div></div>";
  data3.innerHTML = "";

}

setInterval(willekeurigObject, 3000);
```

Comment: make variable names unique or overwrite them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to add up all the values in an array.

https://jsfiddle.net/khzcwnso/

```
var movies = [{title: 'avatar', rating: 2.5}, {title: 'avatar2', rating: 3}, {title: 'avatar3', rating: 5}];

var total = movies.reduce(function(sum, movie){
    return sum + movie.rating;
}, 0);

var average = total / movies.length;
```